# What if my paper is accepted, but later my institution doesn’t allow me to publish in this journal?

Tags: publications, withdraw

My paper was accepted by a publisher; an acceptance letter was mailed to me.
However, later my institution didn’t allow me to publish there, because it the journal isn’t indexed by Scopus? How can I withdraw the paper; is there any issue if I submit my paper to another publisher?

Comment: Can you please add some more details?  What reason might your institution have for allowing you to publish in some venues but not others?  The answer will likely depend on those details.

Comment: You might also want to say which country you are in. The idea of a university censoring where or what you can publish, for example, would be entirely counter to the US notion of academic freedom.

Comment: Thank you.. the reason  is the journal is not Scopus indexed and  my institute doesn't allow me to do so!

Comment: Thank  you #electrique it  helps me ur URl!!!! actually they didn't publish  it  so what do I do if I want to publish in other journal? what are the legal issues in such a  process could any one help me?

Comment: Have you signed an agreement to transfer the paper's copyright to the publisher, or to grant them a license to publish?  If not, you can withdraw the paper unilaterally.  If yes, then you will need the journal's permission to withdraw - if they won't let you, then you will simply have to deal with the consequences at your institution.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not sure that is true. If the university holds a legal claim that can prevent your from publishing then you could not legally given permission  to the publisher.

Comment: @StrongBad: Maybe.  If that's the case, I'd be worried about the fact that OP signed over something that wasn't theirs to transfer.  I'm not a lawyer, but that sounds like fraud, and I'd want to talk to university counsel (and/or my own lawyer).

Comment: It's really unimaginable that the journal would take legal action against you.  Suing would cost them money and alienate authors.  I would just inform them that you're required to withdraw the paper, and submit it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the result of going against the grain. You should have looked first if your university had any rule regarding which journal to publish. This is important even now as you can re-submit to another unwanted journal by the university.

Depending on the limited data given by yourself I suggest you  get a confirmation from the journal that your article will not be published by them. Until that time, do not send your article to another journal for review. 
.
Again I assume that perhaps you wanted to fund the article through university and that is why university refuses article. Is this the case? If it is, then you should either publish without any funding from the university or follow above mentioned suggestion.